# Extension of closed $(1, 1)$-forms

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, complex-geometry

Let $X$ be a compact Kähler manifold and $S \subset X$ a closed complex submanifold. Given a closed $(1, 1)$-form $\alpha$ on $S$, is there always a closed $(1, 1)$-form $\beta$ on a neighborhood of $S$ in $X$ such that $[\beta|_S] = [\alpha]$ in $H^{1, 1}(S, \mathbb{C})$?

**Note.** [This](https://mathoverflow.net/a/58505/392184) mathoverflow answer seems related, but I don't think it answers the above question. The proof of Theorem 4.1 in [arXiv:math/0609617](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0609617) begins by assuming that we have such an extension and pursue by proving positivity results. I fail to see how any of the ideas in the proof would help with the question above. But I might be wrong, so any help in that direction would be great too.

**Addendum** (In reply to Donu Arapura's answer)**.** There is related work by Griffiths (*The extension problem in complex analysis. II. Embeddings with positive normal bundle.* Amer. J. Math. 88 (1966)), showing the obstruction to extending certain analytic objects from $S$ to a neighborhood of $S$ in $X$. For instance, it is proved that if $F \to S$ is a vector bundle which is the restriction of a vector bundle $E \to U$ on a neighborhood $U$ of $S$ in $X$, and $\alpha \in H^q(S, F)$, then the first order obstruction to extending $\alpha$ to an element of $H^q(U, E)$ (possibly after shrinking $U$) lies in $H^{q+1}(S, F \otimes N_S^*)$, where $N_S^*$ is the conormal bundle of $S$ in $X$, and it does not vanish in general. In our case, we can interpret $\alpha$ as an element of $H^1(S, T^*S)$. But this does not immediately fit into Griffiths work, since $T^*S$ does not generally extend to a vector bundle on a neighborhood of $S$ in $X$.

Comment: Wouldn't be enough to let $\beta=\pi^*\alpha$, where  $\pi:T\to S$ is a tubular neighbourhood?

Comment: @DonuArapura We would need a *holomorphic* tubular neighbourhood, which fails to exist in general.

Comment: @DonuArapura See, e.g., https://mathoverflow.net/questions/114414/is-there-any-holomorphic-version-of-the-tubular-neighborhood-theorem

Comment: I got downvoted for this. I'm new here, and I'm not sure I see what's wrong with it. Can someone explain?

Answer (score 2):

Contrary to my earlier comments, I now believe (but I haven't completely checked) that this is false in general. (I prefer not to comment on the paper you linked.) Suppose that $X$ is a Kähler manifold. The form $\alpha$ defines a class in $H^1(S,\Omega_S^1)$. The existence of $\beta$ should imply that $\alpha$ lifts to a class $\alpha'\in H^1(S, \Omega_{S'}^1)$, where $S'$ is the first order neighbourhood of $S$. But there are obstructions, which I believe are nontrivial.

When $\alpha=c_1(L)$, with $L$ a line bundle, then I believe the existence of $\alpha'$ is close to demanding that $L$ lifts to $S'$. But here the obstruction is well known to lie in $H^2(S,\mathcal{O})$, and is  generally nontrivial.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I replied to it in the original post.

Comment: +1 by the way. I'm still not sure how to definitely find a counterexample, but this is useful nonetheless.